# How to bind my listbox to a partial class of itself?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a small problem, suppose I have the following **MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="DragDrop.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Name="ListBoxLeft"  />
        <ListBox Name="ListBoxRight"  Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and now I would simply like bind `<ListBox Name="ListBoxLeft"  />` to my property `public List<User> UserListLeft;`. How can I achieve this? How should I specify the DataContext?

All properties are just simply listed in **MainWindow.xaml.cs**.

Note: I do not use the MVVM model.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor of your MainWindow.xaml.cs add:

```
DataContext=this;
```

then in your MainWindow.xaml, add:

```
 <ListBox Name="ListBoxRight"  Grid.Column="1" ItemSource={Binding UserListLeft} />
```

Please make your UserListLeft as an ObservableCollection, instead of List. To be able to notify any change to the view.

Comment: Dear Alvaro, thank you for your kind response. I was wondering whether it was also possible to do the `DataContext=this;` part in XAML.

Comment: @Snowflake So what you want to do can't be called a "Binding". In this case, I suggest for you to fill it Manually, in the "Set method" of your UserListLeft property. each time you add an "Item" to your list, add also :
ListBoxRight.Items.add(YourItem);

Comment: In XAML top / Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"

Comment: Also, you should have the mainWindow implement INotifyPropertyChanged